# Android M permission dialog not showing

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm currently trying to adapt my application to the new permissions model of Android M.

I'm collecting all the permissions I require, then run

```
Log.i("Permissions", "Requesting permissions: " + permissions);
requestPermissions(requiredPermissions.toArray(new String[requiredPermissions.size()]), requestCodeForPermissions);
```

requiredPermissions holds the permissions I need like `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

That routine is definitely executed as I have the Log line in the logcat:

```
08-07 12:52:46.469: I/Permissions(1674): Requesting permissions: android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED; android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

But the permissions dialog never shows, let alone is onRequestPermissionsResult() called.

What am I doing wrong? Based on some tutorials I found I'm not missing anything.
I only have the emulator for testing, no physical device. This is the about screen from settings:
[Image](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-27930397/EmulatorVersion.png.html)

It might be worth mentioning something else: If I try to open the overview of installed apps from the home screen I only get `launcher3 has exited`. I'm not sure if that might be related.

Does anybody have an idea why it's not showing?

Comment: What version of the M Developer Preview are you using? In v1, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` was not `dangerous` and did not need to be requested manually. That changed in v2, where it works like other `dangerous` permissions like `CAMERA`. Note that `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` is not a `dangerous` permission; you do not have to request it at runtime.

Comment: I have v2.

For the sake of testing I added record audio which is now requested:
08-07 13:49:31.647: I/Permissions(1540): Requesting permissions: android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED; android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE; android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO

This is from my manifest:
     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="MNC"
        android:targetSdkVersion="MNC" />

And this is from the project.properties file:

target=android-MNC
targetSdkVersion=MNC
compileSdkVersion=android-MNC

Am I missing anything that might be obvious for others?

Comment: Do you have the `<uses-permission>` elements in your manifest? The new runtime permissions model does not eliminate the need for `<uses-permission>` elements. It just adds additional requirements for requesting permissions at runtime for select permission groups.

Comment: Yes, my manifest still contains all the old uses-permission elements.

Comment: Well, [this sample app of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Permissions/PermissionMonger) seems to work fine on MNC v2. Compare and contrast what you have with what I have.

Comment: Thanks for that. Well, I don't currently use Android Studio, but still Eclipse. Most tutorials about this mention the build.gradle file for some lines. Could it be Android Studio is a requirement for the permission model?
The actual source code seems identical.

Comment: "Could it be Android Studio is a requirement for the permission model?" -- it's conceivable, at least for the preview. Eclipse might work better once M ships and we have a regular API level number to work with. That being said, since Google is abandoning support for Eclipse at the end of the year, I really encourage you to have a plan for issues like this one, as there will come a time when you literally cannot build what you want using Eclipse+ADT. With luck, Andmore will be able to fill the gap by then.

Comment: in my case i had set a maxsdk for the WRITE permission, because i wasn't ready to deal with permissions(earlier), so i just targeted API 21.
so all i had to do was remove the MAXSDK restriction and it worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the comment from Hilal (thanks a lot!):
In my case my app is indeed using tabhost and the permissions were requested from an Activity inside the tabhost. After starting a separate activity that requests the permissions it is working.

Answer (score 124):

I experienced the same issue but later I realized I forgot to add the permission to the manifest file. After adding the uses-permission tag, the system showed the dialog. Maybe helps someone.

Comment: pfff.wasted almost 2 hours until this post (in manifest was coarse_location in code fine_location)....

Comment: Same here... Thanks !

Comment: Awesome! That's the problem when developing fast! You miss basic things behind. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, me either=))

Comment: But it did not fixed because I also used tabhost and that is probably also problem when you want to show permissin dialog, [found this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37142595/5528870)

Comment: Make sure everything is spelled right, too. I had `android.permissoin.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: Do make sure that the capitalization is the same. Android will happily case-convert when it checks the permission on install, but it does not do so when comparing the requested permission with your manifest.

Comment: Good to know about this.

Answer (score 32):

The [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40775623/3040498) helped me.

I fixed by adding `tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"` like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
```

Comment: This solved my issue with having the permissions denied at runtime.

Answer (score 14):

I experienced the same issue because I was using the negative value as a REQUEST_CODE.

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, -1)
```

After using positive value, the system showed the dialog.
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This was the solution.  Absolutely bizarre that negative numbers cause Android to fail in such a subtle and infuriating way.

Comment: Thanks!, this was my case as I didn't want to attend the callback

Comment: You saved my life

Answer (score 9):

add

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

Note : The Permission which you want to get. Eg: android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION etc.

Comment: This was my issue. Don't get fooled by the official doc telling you to set a maxSdk value. :(

Answer (score 9):

I just had the same problem.
My issue was that I wrote the permission at the wrong place in the manifest.
Make sure the uses permission is outside of application:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="FacePhotoDemo"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

Answer (score 2):

I have also come across a situation where the permission dialog doesn't appear or the application crashes when using the `<uses-permission-sdk23>` element, however the cause appears to be a system bug on current 6.0 devices:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189841

Crash exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and the problem is solved after adding the shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale like this:

```
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

}
```

Comment: This wouldn't change anything

Answer (score 2):

To add to @shanraisshan's answer, the `REQUEST_CODE` actually has to be greater than 0, not just non-negative.

Answer (score 2):

In our code, it was a simple spelling mistake.

We had:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION" />
```

It should be:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I was doing two calls to requestPermissions(), one right after the other. This error message appeared in Logcat (note the misspelling on "request"):

```
Can reqeust only one set of permissions at a time
```

requestPermissions() is actually designed to take multiple requests at once; that's what the String array is for.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the permission I was requesting (WRITE_SETTINGS) was more special and required Settings Activity to launch. So dialog was not showing up.

I had to get its permission using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_WRITE_SETTINGS_PERMISSION);
```

Comment: `WRITE_SETTINGS` is treated as a _special permission_ and requires special handling: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#special_permissions

Answer (score 2):

Yet another cause for not getting the permission dialog to show when requesting a dangerous permission...

I had to do **Build -> Clean Project** and then **Build -> Rebuild Project**. I guess Android Studio didn't pick up on the changes I made in the manifest.

Comment: I wasted half a day to figure out what's wrong with my code. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue caused by the wrong case of the permission constant in the manifest, I was using `read_contacts` in lower case:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_contacts" />
```

After changing `read_contacts` to uppercase it started working as expected

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Permissions are organised into categories so non-critical ones are granted without the dialog being shown.

I found this the hard way with internet permission,  if you're having this issue then changing to a critical permission such as read_contacts will allow you to test your flow and reveal whether the issue is the permission being non-critical or something else.

[Normal protection](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/normal-permissions.html) permissions are listed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/normal-permissions.html)

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest, I changed

```
 <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
```

to

```
 <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     />
```

Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add permission in the manifest file as well.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone of you guys has an application that changes/modifies `WRITE_SETTINGS` and are facing this issue. Check out [CommonsWare's Answer to WRITE_SETTINGS Ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32083622/6911518)

I was facing this issue for 2 weeks and later realised that this issue was due to the fact that `requestPermissions` doesn't work for requesting `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission.
Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had requested "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" in my manifest file and then request for "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" permission in code that's why the Permission Dialog was not opening.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a while it appears it is required to set the value compileSdkVersion to "android-MNC" or as of today to 23. That requires the Gradle build system which then seems to require Android Studio.
At least I couldn't find a single manual about how to set it outside the gradle files.

Comment: I have the same issue and haven't managed to solve it yet. Reading your answer does not really help me solve it? Could you please clarify a bit more? My compileSdkVersion was and still is 23 and I still get this error.

Comment: me too. Your answer worth nothing, because below 23 there was no Runtime Permissions.

Comment: Why is it worth nothing? I merely said it doesn't seem to work to achieve this if one is using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I did all the things said in above answers but still dialog was not showing and then I changed `targetSdkVersion` to `23` in gradle and it appeared . Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public final void validateRequestPermissionsRequestCode(int requestCode) {
       // We use 16 bits of the request code to encode the fragment id when
       // requesting permissions from a fragment. Hence, requestPermissions()
       // should validate the code against that but we cannot override it as we
       // can not then call super and also the ActivityCompat would call back to
       // this override. To handle this we use dependency inversion where we are
       // the validator of request codes when requesting permissions in
       // ActivityCompat.
        if (!mRequestedPermissionsFromFragment
                && requestCode != -1 && (requestCode & 0xffff0000) != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Later I realized that we have to declare each and every permission in manifest (even if one is a subclass of another).
In my case I declared

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

in my manifest and was trying to access user's coarse location.

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
```

Fixed the problem by adding coarse permission as well in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your **targetSdkVersion** to **22**.

Answer (score 0):

had the same (i guess) problem and the solution was removing

```
import <app package>.Manifest;
```

autoimported by Android Studio at the top of the file and substitute it with

```
import android.Manifest;
```

and started working

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution is the string itself

android.permission.READ_CONTACTS

I did Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS which caused silence error (Noting show on the screen).

Make sure that this is correct

Comment: Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS = "android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"

Answer (score 0):

My Android targetSDK version is 28.

I don't see any pop ups shown to user requesting for permission which are listed in android Manifest.xml as .
During both installation, installing .apk using USB and installing app from google play store.
So I added below code in my activity it will ask user permission during runtime

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MyActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1);

Answer (score 0):

I was requesting permission through code, but had missed adding the `<uses-permission ..>` tag in manifest !

Answer (score -1):

Change the final constant value to 1.

```
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE = 1;

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE);
```