# ActivityCompat.requestPermissions not showing dialog box

Tags: java, android, permissions

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RegisterActivity.this,      Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION);
```

i'm trying to use this function on nexus 5 api 23 and its just not showing me the dialog box like its supposed to do, it's just not doing anything.
what could cause the problem? (this code is in the java activity)
i tried changing my minimum api to 23 and use the requestPermissions() without the ActivityCompat but still not working.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.idanayzen.photomap"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

and the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.idanayzen.photomap">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".WrongPhoneNum"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: btw i already tried to change the string to "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" still the same

Comment: Is the permission is blocked?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Here's an example of using `requestPermissions()`:

First, define the permission (as you did in your post) in the manifest, otherwise, your request will automatically be denied:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Next, define a value to handle the permission callback, in onRequestPermissionsResult():

```
private final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_PHONE_STATE=1;
```

Here's the code to call requestPermissions():

```
private void showPhoneStatePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
            showExplanation("Permission Needed", "Rationale", Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, REQUEST_PERMISSION_PHONE_STATE);
        } else {
            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, REQUEST_PERMISSION_PHONE_STATE);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission (already) Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

First, you check if you already have permission (remember, even after being granted permission, the user can later revoke the permission in the App Settings.)

And finally, this is how you check if you received permission or not:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
        int requestCode,
        String permissions[],
        int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PERMISSION_PHONE_STATE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}

private void showExplanation(String title,
                             String message,
                             final String permission,
                             final int permissionRequestCode) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    requestPermission(permission, permissionRequestCode);
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
}

private void requestPermission(String permissionName, int permissionRequestCode) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{permissionName}, permissionRequestCode);
}
```

Comment: isn't it useless to do all of this checking if the requestPermissions is not working? in my code im just checking if i have the permission and if not i call the requestPermissions. and later i guess ill change that.
and i did the requestPermissions syntax exactly as you said but its not working for me.

Comment: Since you didn't post your actual requestPermissions() code, I posted a complete working example.  Works fine for me.

Comment: I posted my actual requestPermissions() code just now. thank you for your help :)

Comment: You're code works for me as well... are you sure you haven't already given yourself permission?  (You can go in to Settings | App | click our app and check the Permissions.)

Comment: I just checked and the permissions are turned off. it's really weird that it works for you and not for me

Comment: Your device or emulator is running Android 6.0, right?  (I know these are basic questions, but always the best place to start ;))  Actually, you couldn't turn off the permission if you weren't.  Have you tried making a new app, just to isolate the issue?

Comment: Glad you have it working, but not knowing why something doesn't work always bugs me.

Comment: @NightSkyDev - what are the requestPermission and showExplanation methods in your example?

Comment: @Phil - Added both to the example.  As you can see, it would be just as easy to call requestPermission directly, and you would need to if you are requesting multiple permissions as this method is just a wrapper to call one permission.

Comment: thanks for highlighting the "First, define the permission (as you did in your post) in the manifest, otherwise, your request will automatically be denied". Mine was like this

<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22"
        tools:replace="maxSdkVersion" />

I changed the "22" to "23"

Comment: @NightSkyDev pretty good answer. Thanks, solved my issue as well

Answer (score 60):

I had the same issue and it turned out to be due to the [manifest merger tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html) pulling in an `android:maxSdkVersion` attribute from a dependency.

To view the actual permissions you're requesting in your APK you can use the `aapt` tool, like this:

```
/path/to/android-sdk/build-tools/version/aapt d permissions /path/to/your-apk.apk
```

in my case, it printed:

```
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' maxSdkVersion='18'
```

even though I hadn't specified a `maxSdkVersion` in my manifest. I fixed this issue by changing `<uses-permission>` in my manifest to:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
```

(where the tools namespace is `http://schemas.android.com/tools`)

Comment: @usman its not necessary that it should work for all, may be your case is different. Please post your question, someone surely resolve your problem :)

Comment: as of now at least, to view the actual permission (merged) manifest, you can view it without any other tools like `aapt`. While you see your AndroidManifest.xml from Android Studio, look at the bottom tab, just click on the `Merged Manifest` tab.

Answer (score 31):

I had a need to request permission for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` but was not getting a pop-up despite trying all of the different suggestions mentioned.

The culprit in the end was HockeyApp. It uses manifest merging to include its own permission for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` except it applies a max sdk version onto it.

The way to get around this problem is to include it in your Manifest file but with a replace against it, to override the HockeyApp's version and success!

> 4.7.2 Other dependencies requesting the external storage permission (SDK version 5.0.0 and later) To be ready for Android O,
>   HockeySDK-Android 5.0.0 and later limit the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
>   permission with the maxSdkVersion filter. In some use cases, e.g.
>   where an app contains a dependency that requires this permission,
>   maxSdkVersion makes it impossible for those dependencies to grant or
>   request the permission. The solution for those cases is as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>
```

> It will cause that other attributes from low
>   priority manifests will be replaced instead of being merged.

https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/hockeyapp-for-android-sdk#permissions-advanced

Comment: Thank you, It was my problem all this day.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 16):

It could be not a problem with a single line of your code.

On some devices (I don't recall if it is in stock Android) the Permission dialog includes a check box labeled "Never ask again". If you click Deny with the box checked then you won't be prompted again for that permission, it will automatically be denied to the app. To revert this, you have to go into Settings -> App -> Permissions and re--enable that perm for the app. Then turn it off to deny it again. You may have to open the app before turning it off again, not sure.

I don't know if your Nexus has it. Maybe worth a try.

Comment: I had this situation. The best way out I could think of was to check for `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` and adjust the UI to explain the user that the permissions had to be manually set and open `Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`.

Answer (score 15):

Replace:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{"Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"}, 225);
```

with:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 225);
```

[The actual string for that permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE) is not `"Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"`. Use the symbol `Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`.

Comment: not work for me. my app is configured to work from 16 to 23 sdk version

Comment: you should use android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Answer (score 5):

In my case, target sdk 33 to 32 solves it

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Not sure why, but at least i know its related to target sdk and can investigate further.

Comment: I agree @DSDmark. I will try to add from now on.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another experience I'd like to share with you guys. The problem showed up after I implemented the following code to check for BLE access permission:

```java
final String requiredPermission = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && targetSdkVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) ?
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION :
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
```

I meant to distinguish between FINE and COARSE location permission requests, both had been defined in the manifest. When checking for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission, the "Request permission" dialog never poped up but `onRequestPermissionsResult` was always called with PERMISSION_DENIED (in case permission was not enabled in app settings). So I removed the check for BUILD.SDK and checked only for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and voilla the missing dialog showed up.

```java
final String requiredPermission = android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
```

did the trick.

The Manifest source contains:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

but the apk contained `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` only. Sometime during build, the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` had been removed.

I hope this might help somebody having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I updated my target SDK version from 22 to 23 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't random luck.  The reason why is that 23 is when Android started interpreting `<uses-permission>` as a future code action instead of an on-install demand.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to write the permissions without extra spaces in the manifest. In my case, I had:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE " />
```

But look, at the end, there's an extra space. Just write it the right way:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And it's working now.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this was related to them getting more granular with permissions in 33, related to requesting read_external_storage.

This is the kotlin code I'm using to check and request access in Jan 2023.

```
private fun checkPermissions():Boolean{
        // version 33 gets more granular
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, arrayOf(
                        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO // why isn't this plural too
                    ),
                    1
                )
                return false
            }
        }else{
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, arrayOf(
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    ),
                    1
                )
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

I also had to add all 3 of these to my manifest, to support apis 31-33.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"  />
```

Answer (score 2):

## ***No matter what you do, Check if you declare Permission you need in the Manifest file.***

```
    <!--Declaring the required permissions-->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Then go to next steps..

Answer (score 2):

I followed the top answer, but still didn't work. This simple issue wasted me many days. For my case, I'm trying to get access for `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. At the end, I found for this particular permission, we can't use `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`, instead I have to use `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`. And to check if the permission is there, we also need to use a different API: `Environment.isExternalStorageManager()` instead of `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`, not sure why they design in such an inconsistent way cause so much confusions.

I get my issue resolved following: [How to obtain MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64250814/how-to-obtain-manage-external-storage-permission)

And also this is mentioned in SDK document of: [manage-all-files](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files).

Comment: life saver.. no one tells u how messed up things are than they actually look :)

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was requesting a group mistakenly instead of the actual permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The above information is good, but setting `targetSdkVersion` to 23 (or higher) is **critical** for Android to interpret the `<uses-permission>` tag in the manifest as "I will ask in code" instead of "I demand upon installation."  Lots of sources will tell you that you need the `<uses-permission>` tag, but no one says why and if you don't have that value set, you're going to be as confused as I was for hours on end.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem in Samsung S8 and N8 (havent found in any other)

so the problem is in the manifest file uses-permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
android:requiredFeature="true" />
```

For some reason, the attribute `android:requiredFeature` is the culprit. and I haven't found the explanation on why.

to solve simply remove it,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.I updated to **buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"** It all of a sudden worked. Hope this helps anyone having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and solved it by replacing Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE with android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was I had an invalid request code. I choose 0xDEADBEEF as a request code and it was silently failing (maybe it's cast to something smaller than 32-bit somewhere internally?) If I choose 255 everything worked fine as NightSkyDev described above.

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)) state that `requestCode`, should be ≥ 0. 0xDEADBEEF is < 0.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me.  It turned out I was requesting ALL permissions, when I needed to filter to just DANGEROUS permissions, and it suddenly started working.

```
fun requestPermissions() {
    val missingDangerPermissions = PERMISSIONS
            .filter { ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, it) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED }
            .filter { this.getPackageManager().getPermissionInfo(it, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).protectionLevel == PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_DANGEROUS } // THIS FILTER HERE!

    if (missingDangerPermissions.isNotEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Requesting dangerous permission to $missingDangerPermissions.")
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                missingDangerPermissions.toTypedArray(),
                REQUEST_CODE_REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS);
        return
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "We had all the permissions we needed (yay!)")
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you get the variable of ContextCompat? I tried but variable not foundresult?

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was in the manifest: the permission was in uppercase. Android Studio suggest me the permissions in uppercase. I don't care about that and it took me two hours to fixe this problem.

The right syntaxe for permission is 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that right after making the request, my main activity launched another activity. That superseded the dialog so it was never seen.

Comment: Hi buddy, I think this is my case, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Just change the flow of events in the app. Do NOT launch another activity right after you request a permission!

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:
Add the following to your Manifest file:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" **tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"** />

Check this article, it fixed it for me:

https://nphau.medium.com/android-request-permissions-not-showing-a-dialog-box-b7f2067d7b09

Answer (score -1):

it happen to me i was running it on API 23 and i had to use the code to request permission like this code below put it on on create method. note that MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_LOCATION is an integer that is equal to 1 example int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_LOCATION = 1:

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{ Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_LOCATION);
        }

Answer (score -4):

Maybe this solution could help anyone 
rather than:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

use :

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

so we add `android.` to `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`