# "ActivityCompat.requestPermissions" not showing dialog

Tags: android

I am developing an app.

It's targetSdkVersion is 19.

But when i install my app on android 7.1 and revoke the permissions in settings, my app not behaves properly because of leak of permissions.so in order to solve the problem i add a test on needed permissions and try to use "`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`" to ask for permissions when it tests failed, but now when i revoke needed permissions,

"`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`" will not show dialog any more.and i am sure "`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`" is excuted,i guess the reason is it's `targetSdkVersion` is lower than 23, so when "`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`" checks for missing permissions, all the needed permissions are deemed granted but in fact some of them are revoked.
the problem is not the same as [ActivityCompat.requestPermissions not showing dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484767/activitycompat-requestpermissions-not-showing-dialog-box), it targetSdkVersion is 23 so that android runtime permission goes for it's situation, but the targetSdkVersion of my app is 19. so it is not suitable for android runtime permission.
now what can i do to ask permissions?
thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActivityCompat.requestPermissions not showing dialog box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484767/activitycompat-requestpermissions-not-showing-dialog-box)

Comment: make the targetSdk 23 or above

Comment: but i can't do that ，so is there a way to solve the problem ?

Comment: as i know request permission only show in device have API 23 and above. other devices it take permission when we define in manifest

Comment: It only show system permission dialog in 23+

Comment: so how can i  request the permissions which is revoked in android 6.0 and  above, and targetSdk of my app is 19..

Comment: Permissions can only be requested when targetSdk is 23 or above. You won't be able to do it with lower SDK.

Comment: that means when i revoke permissions of the app(sdkTargetVersion is 19)  in android 6.0+ in settings，there is nothing i can do to request the revoked permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

discovered that the permission request popup is hidden by the app screen. resolved in the app I'm developing with

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    ...
}
```