# How do I get the user's current location in a map fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I am currently using Google Maps in one of my fragments. The goal is to obtain the user's current location. So far, I was only able to do this with the Google Maps embedded in an activity, and not in a fragment.

This app I am developing is written in Kotlin. So far, the solutions I have found that are written in Java are either deprecated or do not work at all.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45958226/3808178).

Comment: what exactly is a problem for you in a fragment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024079/getting-user-current-location-using-fused-location-provider/74101488#74101488