# Getting user current location using fused location provider

Tags: android, location, android-fusedlocation

I am using google play service location api (fused location provider) to get user current location. In some cases it takes too much time to return the results and sometimes it takes quite less time to return the reslts for the same device. In both cases user was indoor. I could not understand which is the reason behind this scenario.

```
public class SelfAttendanceFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {


protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 1;
private static Double LATITUDE_DHAKA;
private static Double LONGITUDE_DHAKA;

LoadingDialog mLoadingDialog;
double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;
Handler mHandler;
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
LocationManager locationManager;
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
Location location;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private String address;
private String remarks = "";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_self_attendance, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    /*if (!checkPermissionGranted()) {
        askForPermission();
    }*/

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

                && getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        } else {
               startAction();
        }
    } else {
        startAction();
    }


}

private void startAction(){
    mLoadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(getContext(), getString(R.string.fetching_location));

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    doCheckPermissionForGps();

    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            List<Location> locationList = locationResult.getLocations();
            for (Location loc : locationList) {
                if (loc.getLatitude() != 0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0) {
                    location = loc;
                    checkLocationandAddToMap();
                     break;
                }
            }

        }
    };
}


private void doCheckPermissionForGps() {

    Boolean isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (isGpsEnabled && mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        requestLocationUpdates();
    } else if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    } else if (!isGpsEnabled) {
        displayLocationSettingsRequest(getContext());
    }

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10 / 2);
}

private String getAddressByLattitudeAndLongitude() {
    String address;
    try {
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());

        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 5); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5

        address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        if (address.isEmpty()) {
            address = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        address = "";
    }
    return address;
}

private void displayLocationSettingsRequest(Context context) {
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}



 @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private void requestLocationUpdates() {
    if(isAdded() && getActivity() != null){
        mLoadingDialog.showDialogWithText("Fetching location using GPS...");
    }

    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    switch (resultCode) {
        case -1:
            requestLocationUpdates();

            break;
        case 0:
            displayLocationSettingsRequest(getContext());
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }


}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        displayLocationSettingsRequest(getContext());
    } else {
        requestLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mFusedLocationClient != null) {
        mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    try{
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.clear();

        LATITUDE_DHAKA = 23.777176;
        LONGITUDE_DHAKA = 90.399452;
        try {

            boolean success = mMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            getContext(), R.raw.style_map));


        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        CameraPosition camPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(LATITUDE_DHAKA, LONGITUDE_DHAKA)).zoom(10)                   // Sets the zoom
                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .build();

        if (mMap != null)
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(camPosition));

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
                doCheckPermissionForGps();
                return false;
            }
        });


        View locationButton = ((View) mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                locationButton.getLayoutParams();
        // position on right bottom
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 100);
    } catch (Exception ex){

    }



}

private void checkLocationandAddToMap() {

    //MarkerOptions are used to create a new Marker.You can specify location, title etc with MarkerOptions
    if (location != null) {

        CameraPosition camPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .build();

        if (mMap != null)
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(camPosition));

    }
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

            && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        startAction();
    } else {
        CustomSnackbarError.showMessageFromFragment(getContext(),"Permission is necessary" +
                " to enable this feature");
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
    }
}

/*@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                   *//* && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[3] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[4] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[5] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[6] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[7] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED*//*
                    ) {

                //checkForUpdate();
                startAction();

            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}*/

private boolean checkPermissionGranted() {

  /*  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }*/

   /* if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }*/
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void askForPermission() {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(),
            new String[]{
                    /*Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,*/
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            },
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    dismisLoadingDialog();
}
private void dismisLoadingDialog(){
    if(mLoadingDialog != null && mLoadingDialog.isShowing()){
        mLoadingDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time GPS provider takes much time to fetch location when the user is within the building. In that case, you must have to fetch location from the network provider for faster results. GPS works very well outside the building but has trouble to fetch location from within. Please allow fetching location from both network & GPS provider for improved result.

Answer (score 0):

The way android has implemented and created this fusedlocationprovider library is it takes two types of location updates: 
1 -> Network Based
2 -> GPS

As when user try to fetch the location from indoor or any place where GPS has no much space for getting location from satellite it uses network.

so, when you are working indoor you will see that it is troubling fetching location. But as you said sometimes it takes lesser time and sometimes it takes much time.

The possible scenario is Whenever you request for location it will go and try to find the location if there is already location taken by other application and if there is location you will get it. Otherwise it will try to find the location by its own and next time you search for it as it has already it will give you directly.

And you have used GPS Provider, use Network provider as well.

Let me know if it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code for getting the current location faster using fused location - **FusedLocationProviderClient** :

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val PERMISSION_ID = 1000
    private lateinit var mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        getCurrentLocation()
    }

    private fun getCurrentLocation() {
        if (isLocationEnabled()) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                requestPermissions()
                return
            }
            val tokenSource = CancellationTokenSource()
            val token = tokenSource.token
            mFusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, token)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    val location: Location? = task.result
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "${location!!.latitude} and ${location.longitude}",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    private fun isLocationEnabled(): Boolean {
        val locationManager: LocationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
        )
    }
    private fun requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ),
            PERMISSION_ID
        )
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_ID) {
            if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                getCurrentLocation()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
```