# Getting lastLocation null using fusedlocationclient inside fragment

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments, kotlin, location

I'm using fusedlocationclient to get the current user location, but somehow the lasLocation is null.

**Here's my Location Fragment:**

```
package com.example.atry.MakeComplaint

import Retrofit.INodeJS
import Retrofit.Observables
import Retrofit.RetrofitClient
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.*
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentSender
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.*
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView

import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
import com.ashiqur.weatherapp.utils.GPSUtils
import com.example.atry.R
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException
import com.google.android.gms.dynamic.SupportFragmentWrapper
import com.google.android.gms.location.*
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_complaint_details.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_location.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_location.view.*
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Response
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.Observer
import java.util.Optional.empty
import java.util.jar.Manifest
import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback


class LocationFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?)= false

    private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var mapView : MapView
    lateinit var myAPI: INodeJS
    var MyCategory: Observables.ComplaintType?=null
    private var listener: OnLocationFragmentInteractionListener? = null


    var objectComplaint =
        Observables.Complaint(
        1 , "dummy problem" ,
        "url" ,
        Observables.Location("99","99"),
        Observables.ComplaintType("Smell", "null"),
        Observables.Status(2 , "Unresolved")

    )


    //for updating user's location/ for current location

    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback
    private lateinit var lastLocation: Location



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val permissions = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        requestPermissions( permissions,0)


        getLocationUpdates()


        //INIT API

        val retrofit = RetrofitClient.instanc
        myAPI = retrofit.create(INodeJS::class.java)

    }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val v = inflater.inflate(com.example.atry.R.layout.fragment_location, container, false)


        mapView = v.findViewById(R.id.maps)
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mapView.onResume()




       try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity()!!.getApplicationContext());
    } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
        sendEx.printStackTrace();
    }

        mapView.getMapAsync(this)

        v.backToList.setOnClickListener {
            backFragment()

        }

        v.forwardToDescription.setOnClickListener{
            getAllData()


        }

        return v
    }



    /**
     * call this method in onCreate
     * onLocationResult call when location is changed
     */
    private fun getLocationUpdates() {

        //with fusedLocationClient

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context!!)

        locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.interval = 1000
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = 5000
        locationRequest.smallestDisplacement = 170f // 170 m = 0.1 mile
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY //set according to your app function


        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
                locationResult ?: return

                if (locationResult.locations.isNotEmpty()) {
                    // get latest location
                    lastLocation = locationResult.lastLocation
                    Log.d("lastlocation",lastLocation.toString())

                    // use your location object
                    // get latitude , longitude and other info from this

                }
            }
        }
    }




    //Places the marker on the map and changes its style.


    //start location updates

    private fun startLocationUpdates() {


        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,
            locationCallback,
            null /* Looper */
        )
    }

    // stop location updates
    private fun stopLocationUpdates() {
        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
    }



    // start receiving location update when activity  visible/foreground

    override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mapView.onResume()
        startLocationUpdates()

    }

    // stop receiving location update when activity not visible/foreground

    override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mapView.onPause()
        stopLocationUpdates()

    }

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

override public fun onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory()
}

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        map = googleMap!!
        map.uiSettings?.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
        map.isMyLocationEnabled = true



        val marker = MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(lastLocation.latitude,lastLocation.longitude)).title("hello maps")

        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))

        map.addMarker(marker)

        val cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder().target(LatLng(lastLocation.latitude,lastLocation.longitude)).zoom(12f).build()
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition))


    }

    private fun backFragment() {
        val manager = (context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
        manager.popBackStackImmediate()
    }

}
```

Also, if someone could just get this working by using location manager or something else I would really appreciate it. Or maybe a link or video where I could follow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441384/fusedlocationapi-getlastlocation-always-null

Comment: The answer you proposed is in Java. And I am unable to convert it to kotlin. Is there a Kotlin version of it? Also FusedLocationApi is now deprecated.

Comment: here link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958226/get-location-android-kotlin