# Is 'constructor LocationRequest()' deprecated in google maps v2?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2, google-location-services

I stumbled upon this message recently, and I was pretty sure that this constructor wasn't deprecated in prior versions to 18.0.0, but I cannot find information anywhere that this one has been deprecated either.

And what should we use instead, is there another way to create a `locationRequest` ?

[image: message complaining that LocationRequest() is deprecated]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`LocationRequest.create().apply{ ... }` is now also deprecated.

Please use `LocationRequest.Builder()` instead. I.E. like this:

(`locationInterval`, `locationFastestInterval` and `locationMaxWaitTime` corresponds to the values used before when using `create()`)

```
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, locationInterval)
            .setWaitForAccurateLocation(false)
            .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(locationFastestInterval)
            .setMaxUpdateDelayMillis(locationMaxWaitTime)
            .build()
```

Please read more here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationRequest.Builder

and here:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.Builder

Comment: Not sure if this is how Kotlin works but for Java one would need the `new` before `LocationRequest.Builder(...)`

Comment: @AnatolBivol In kotlin you normally don't need it.

Comment: `Builder` has only one param, see the link added in answer

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko, yes, you are right. I referenced wrong link, I added the actual link below as an alternative.

Comment: This is the new correct answer for this question. I had this way built out already and just wanted to confirm the new methods relation to the old field names. This confirmed my thoughts right away without even needing to check docs. @RoarGrønmo Thank you!

Answer (score 136):

Yes, the LocationRequest constructor is deprecated. You can use its static method `LocationRequest.create()` to create a location request.

Kotlin:

```
locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
    interval = 100
    fastestInterval = 50
    priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    maxWaitTime = 100
}
```

Java:

```
locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
    .setInterval(100)
    .setFastestInterval(3000) 
    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
    .setMaxWaitTime(100);
```

**Update**

As @Shimon pointed out **LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY** is now deprecated, so instead use
**Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY**

Comment: Ahh !! Very good ! From which version was this one introduced ?

Comment: I think after version 18.0.0 constructor was deprecated. LocationRequest.create() always were there to create a request, however after version 18 they have added `setWaitForAccurateLocation(true)` to your LocationRequest.

Comment: now it is deprecated

Comment: `LocationRequest.create()` is now deprecated. You should use `LocationRequest.Builder()`

Comment: @JoaquinIurchuk `LocationRequest.Builder` requires API31, so what shoud we do?

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko make sure you're using `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.0"`. This way you should not be using the LocationBuilder from API 31 but the Play Services instead.

Comment: API 33, `LocationRequest.create()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 13):

This line now deprecated:
priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

replace with
priority = Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

Answer (score 6):

For JAVA, I have fixed it by using below code

```
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
```

Inside onCreate()

```
locationRequest = new LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 100)
            .setWaitForAccurateLocation(false)
            .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(2000)
            .setMaxUpdateDelayMillis(100)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who faces this error in `geolocator 8.0.1` of Flutter.
Try to edit `FusedLocationClient.java:199` for now. Then wait for author to update the pub package

From

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
```

To

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
```

This is the `LocationRequest` class
[image]

Answer (score 5):

***UPDATE:***

Constant *`PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`* is deprecated use  *`Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`*  instead.

```
 private fun updateLocationTracking(isTracking: Boolean) {
        if(isTracking) {
            if(TrackingUtility.hasLocationPermissions(this)) {
                val request = LocationRequest.create().apply {
                    interval = LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL
                    fastestInterval = FASTEST_LOCATION_INTERVAL
                    priority =  Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
                }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

May 2023 Kotlin:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest

locationRequest = LocationRequest.Builder(1000L).setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).build()
```

Comment: For Priority like PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, please use .setPriority(). Also apply is not needed for such requests as they return the same Builder specifically to be chained

Comment: @George I updated my answer to show the alternative but what's the difference?

Comment: Thank you!
As for Builder - not much a difference, just avoiding using two builder patterns at the same time
As for .setPriority() - setGranularity() with Priority.* constants gives an error

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) two different LocationRequests

This post is discussing google maps however for those who are looking for location updates outside google maps there have also been some recent changes

HIGH_ACCURACY is set using setQuality(LocationRequest.QUALITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)

```
val fastLocationRequests = LocationRequest.Builder(1000L) // interval specified in millis so this is every 1 second
    .setQuality(LocationRequest.QUALITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
    .setMaxUpdateDelayMillis(0L) // Note 0 represents no batching allowed 
    .build()
```

Use of the alternative Builder()

```
val slowLocationRequests = LocationRequest.Builder(fastLocationRequests)
    .setIntervalMillis(60000L) // once per minute
    .build()
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationRequest.Builder)

Answer (score 0):

```
 LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create() //if you want access of variable
                            .setInterval(100)
                            .setFastestInterval(3000)
                            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                            .setNumUpdates(1)
                            .setMaxWaitTime(100);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30737947)

Answer (score 0):

I too got stuck with this. every other day they deprecate one method and post new ones.
you can use this code snippet:
`locationRequest = new LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, locationInterval) .setWaitForAccurateLocation(false) .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(locationFastestInterval) .setMaxUpdateDelayMillis(locationMaxWaitTime) .build();`
declare all the variables before.