# Marshmallow won't show permission window

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an app that needs write calendar now considered "critical" so I following the guidelines [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) I have added in Activity onCreate this cote

```
private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR = 1453;
  ...
boolean hasPermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    if (!hasPermission) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(parentActivity,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR},
                    REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR);
    }
```

But this doesn't show any dialog.

In addition seems I should ad also this code block to handle response

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                //reload my activity with permission granted or use the features what required the permission
            } else
            {
                Toast.makeText(parentActivity, "The app was not allowed to write to your calendar.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**The Android Target SDK is 23 and is correct. So the cause of the problem is different from that proposed in possible duplicate question.**

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: Marsmellow. The method suggested by Niefs Works... I don't know why the official sample has refused to work

Comment: `if (!permission_ok) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {` is wrong and does not compile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android M permission dialog not showing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878501/android-m-permission-dialog-not-showing)

Comment: @njzk2 this was an error happened when did the synthesis of the code to post here without copy the whole class. Yet edited.

Comment: why someone has downvoted the accepted answer and my question?

Comment: @AndreaF still does not work. You are comparing an int to a boolean. that does not compile

Comment: @AndreaF I downvoted your question because the code you posted does not compile, and therefore cannot be the code that causes your problem.

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for determining permission status can be simplified to this:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(parentActivity, 
                                      new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_CALENDAR},
                                      REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR); 
}
```

Your `Activity` does not have to implement anything, overriding the `onRequestPermissionsResult` will be sufficient.

Comment: why someone has downvoted this answer and my question?

Comment: @Niels Masdorp Formatting issues in answer, maybe?

Comment: I had some false information about the implementation in the second part of my answer, maybe that is why. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Developers need to handle the permission on marshmallow manually now ?

Answer (score 0):

To the second part of the question:

You can override onRequestPermissionsResult in your activity or in your fragment. If you choose to do so in fragment instead of activity you should add something like this in your activity (in order to pass the callback to your fragment):

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    for (Fragment frag : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {

        if (frag != null) {
                frag.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```